# JFreeChart using Large Numbers as Values

Tags: jfreechart

I am currently working on a project using JFreeChart. I got everything working except when I start using large numbers, it goes all funny.

```
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset(); 
    dataset.addValue(1000, "Cars", "2015");    
    dataset.addValue(5000, "Bikes", "2015");
    return dataset;
```

Output from above works perfect, but when I do this:

```
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset(); 
    dataset.addValue(999999999, "Cars", "2015");    
    dataset.addValue(999999999, "Bikes", "2015");
    return dataset;
```

The 999999999 is converted to something like 1E7, 2E7, etc, etc.
How do I format it to show correctly?

This is my chart code.

```
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("My Title", "", "", catdata, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = chart.createBufferedImage(780, 170, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, null);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", out);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setNumberFormatOverride()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setNumberFormatOverride-java.text.NumberFormat-) and pass in a suitable `NumberFormat`. Hover over any bar to see the exact value in a tool tip.

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(formatter);
```

[image]

Comment: WORKS 100%. Thank you very much.