# Exponential tick on linear yAxis - JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, exponential, yaxis

I have a chart with a logarithmic yAxis like this one:
[image: logarithmic chart]

As we can see, the yAxis have exponential ticks (I setted it that way with `yAxis.setExpTickLabelsFlag(true);`). Here is the same chart with a linear axis (the one by default when creating a `xylineChart`):

[image: linear chart]

Unfortunately, my values on the yAxis can't be formatted with exponential ticks because it is not a `LogarithmicAxis`. How can I force it to?

Comment: `NumberAxis::setNumberFormatOverride`?

Comment: @trashgod it seems to be the way to achieve it thank you. I used `yAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("0.######E0"));` but I want to set the exponential as a lower case like `1e5`. Replacing the `E` by `e` give me an illegal argument error. By the way, don't hesitate to post is as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @trashgod either this or make the ticks of the `logarithmicAxis` to upper case. I want something symetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33595830/230513), you can invoke [`setNumberFormatOverride()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to set the desired [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). You can invoke the [`setExponentSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#setExponentSeparator-java.lang.String-) method of [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) to set the desired exponent separator.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setExponentSeparator("e");
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.######E0", symbols);
yAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(format);
```

Alternatively, you should be able to modify the [`numberFormatterObj`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogarithmicAxis.html#numberFormatterObj) of [`LogarithmicAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogarithmicAxis.html) in a custom implementation of [`setupNumberFmtObj()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogarithmicAxis.html#setupNumberFmtObj--), seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogarithmicAxis.html#line.295), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for.